# How to avoid MailKit changing transfer encoding of text/plain and text/html parts?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm using `MimeMessage.Load()` and `SmtpClient.Send()` to load and send `.eml` files. Problem is that MailKit changes UTF-8 `text/plain` part with no transfer encoding to UTF-8 with `base64`, and `text/html` part with UTF-8 and no transfer-encoding is changed into UTF-8 with `quoted-printable`. Can this be avoided? Ideally, I would like to send the eml files exactly as they are, with only minimal changes to `To` and `From` headers.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the SMTP server that is changing this? If you write the message using `message.WriteTo("filename.txt")` right before calling SmtpClient.Send(), does it have the rewritten headers? If not, then it's probably the SMTP server.

Comment: @jstedfast Writing the message to file before sending did not change the transfer encoding of the parts. I also tried sending the original eml file using febootimail tool and the t-encoding also did not change, when I viewed the received message's source in Thunderbird. Could it be caused by `SmtpClient`?

Comment: I just realized that if your text part has UTF-8 text (non-ASCII) and there's no Content-Transfer-Encoding set, then SmtpClient needs to force the encoding down to whatever your SMTP server supports (it essentially calls `message.Prepare (EncodingConstraints.SevenBit)` or `message.Prepare (EncodingConstraints.EightBit)` depending on what the server supports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending a message, MailKit's SmtpClient will [Prepare](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_Prepare.htm) the message for transport given the SMTP server's encoding constraints (which are either: 7bit, 8bit, or binary depending on what the server supports).

The SmtpClient's Prepare() method is virtual and so *can* be overridden.

The default implementation essentially just calls [MimeMessage.Prepare](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MimeMessage_Prepare.htm).

What this method does is walks the tree of MIME parts making sure that every MIME part has content that adheres to the encoding constraint provided. If and when it finds a part that does not conform, it calculates the best Content-Transfer-Encoding to use and then sets that.

Comment: So would overriding SmtpClient's `Prepare()` with an empty implementation achieve my goal of leaving the message the same as original eml file?

Comment: Yes, it should.